# How to reduce the number of (overlapping) constraints in a linear program?

Tags: optimization, linear-transformations, linear-programming, constraints

I am trying to solve a linear program with more than $7$ million constraints in around $5000$ variables. It could not be solved on my computer. In the constraints, there is overlap, e.g.,

$$ \begin{aligned} 2X_1 + 3X_2 &\leq 5 \\ 1X_1 + 2X_2 &\leq 5 \end{aligned} $$

In this example, it is pretty clear that the second constraint is dominated by the first constraint because if the first constraint is smaller than $5$ then automatically the second constraint is smaller than $5$. But some examples are not that easy to identify, for example, if a constraint is dominated by a combination of other constraints. Does someone have an idea how I could find all the unnecessary constraints to reduce the number of constraints in the linear program (all the variables should be larger than $0$).

Comment: High performance LP solvers have advanced pre-solver algorithms which will do similar things to reduce the size of the problem. Also this is not considered a very large problem for advanced LP solvers, and unless the problem is completely dense you should be able to solve this using a standard PC (assuming this is a continuous LP).

Comment: To build on @ErwinKalvelagen's comment, Gurobi has built in pre-solve that will output redundant constraints while removing them before solving the linear program.  Additionally, if the constraints lead to infeasibility, you can call the computeIIS() method to see which constraints must be removed or modified, which can be very helpful.

Comment: Check some references about linear optimization. There are already implemented programs such as simplex algorithm in python for example, but in many programming languages too.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a distinguishable pattern amongst all your constraints, then you can check for which constraint types dominate the other and remove all the non-dominant constraints.

For example, let’s consider your given example:
$2X_1+3X_2≤5$ and  $1X_1+2X_2≤5$. Graphically, this would look like so (with the red shaded region being the constraint $2X_1+3X_2≤5$, and the blue shaded region being the $1X_1+2X_2≤5$ constraint):

[image]

Clearly, the $2X_1+3X_2≤5$ constraint dominates the $1X_1+2X_2≤5$ constraint by covering, and shrinking, a region of feasible points within the other constraint. For each constraint type, meaning if there are constraints that are of the form $-X_1 + X_2 \le 5$ or $X_1 - X_2 \le 5$, or ones that have more or less variables and significant sign flips, you’ll need to check the coefficients and right-hand-sides and find ones that dominates all the other constraints of its same signs and characteristics, and remove all the constraints that are being dominated by this most prominent one (from the mentioned example, we’d remove $1X_1+2X_2≤5$ from the model.) This would be done algorithmically of course, before you would hand off the model to a LP solver.